# Inequality about real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x,y\in [1/2,1]$ be two real numbers such that $x\geq y$ and let $p\in\mathbb{N}$. My question is whether or not we have the inequality

\begin{equation}\nonumber
x^{p} + (1-x)^{p} - y^{p} - (1-y)^{p}\geq 0
\end{equation}

I think that is true, but i'm impossible to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show that $f(x)=x^{p}+(1-x)^{p}$ is an increasing function on $[\frac 1  2,1]$ by showing that $f'(x) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kavi Rama said,
Let $f(x)=x^p+(1-x)^p$ where $p \in \mathit N $ & $x \in \left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$.
Then $f'(x)=px^{p-1}-p(1-x)^{p-1}=p\{x^{p-1}-(1-x)^{p-1}\}\geq 0$.Since $x \geq 1-x$ in $\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$
and $x^p$ is an increasing $\forall p \in \mathit N,\forall x \in \left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$.

$\therefore$ $f(x)$ is increasing in the given interval. Thus the inequality holds.